Laravel app crashes when I call fwrite for one string specifically
I have this helper function I use to log (into the serverside output) some events in my laravel app and is just working fine, but for a reason I can't understand it fails with this specific case:
if(!defined('STDIN'))  define('STDIN',  fopen('php://stdin',  'rb'));
if(!defined('STDOUT')) define('STDOUT', fopen('php://stdout', 'wb'));
if(!defined('STDERR')) define('STDERR', fopen('php://stderr', 'wb'));

class Funcoes{
 public static function consolelog(...$args): void{
    foreach ($args as $arg) {
        if (is_object($arg) || is_array($arg) || is_resource($arg)) {
            $output = print_r($arg, true);
        } else {
            $output = (string) $arg;
        }

        fwrite(STDOUT, $output . "\n");
     }
 }
}

In a middleware I verify a case where I want to abort a request but instead the app is just crashing when I try to print the string " URI:" and it makes no sense to me why is it happening just for this case:
Funcoes::consolelog("Requisição inválida, headers:\n");
Funcoes::consolelog(getallheaders());
Funcoes::consolelog(" Remote addr:");
Funcoes::consolelog($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
Funcoes::consolelog(" URI:"); // it fails here without even printing the string
Funcoes::consolelog($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
abort(400);

Error message:

In ServeCommand.php line 381:


Undefined array key 1

Php -v output (in case it's useful):
$ php -v
PHP 8.3.11 (cli) (built: Aug 28 2024 22:31:38) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.3.11, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.3.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2024, by Derick Rethans

The full stack trace in laravel logs:
[2024-09-21 20:52:46] local.ERROR: Undefined array key 1 {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined array key 1 at /home/user/src/LaravelProj/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ServeCommand.php:381)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/user/src/LaravelProj/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(256): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError()
#1 /home/user/src/LaravelProj/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ServeCommand.php(381): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\{closure}()
#2 /home/user/src/LaravelProj/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ServeCommand.php(306): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\ServeCommand->getRequestPortFromLine()
#3 /home/user/src/LaravelProj/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Traits/EnumeratesValues.php(257): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\ServeCommand->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\{closure}()
#4 /home/user/src/LaravelProj/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ServeCommand.php(279): Illuminate\\Support\\Collection->each()
#5 /home/user/src/LaravelProj/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ServeCommand.php(261): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\ServeCommand->flushOutputBuffer()
#6 /home/user/src/LaravelProj/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php(1306): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\ServeCommand->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\{closure}()
#7 /home/user/src/LaravelProj/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php(1417): Symfony\\Component\\Process\\Process->Symfony\\Component\\Process\\{closure}()
#8 /home/user/src/LaravelProj/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php(1337): Symfony\\Component\\Process\\Process->readPipes()
#9 /home/user/src/LaravelProj/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php(860): Symfony\\Component\\Process\\Process->updateStatus()
#10 /home/user/src/LaravelProj/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ServeCommand.php(105): Symfony\\Component\\Process\\Process->isRunning()
#11 /home/user/src/LaravelProj/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\ServeCommand->handle()
#12 /home/user/src/LaravelProj/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(43): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#13 /home/user/src/LaravelProj/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(95): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure()
#14 /home/user/src/LaravelProj/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(35): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod()
#15 /home/user/src/LaravelProj/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(690): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call()
#16 /home/user/src/LaravelProj/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(213): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call()
#17 /home/user/src/LaravelProj/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(279): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute()
#18 /home/user/src/LaravelProj/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(182): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run()
#19 /home/user/src/LaravelProj/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1045): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run()
#20 /home/user/src/LaravelProj/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(316): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand()
#21 /home/user/src/LaravelProj/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(167): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun()
#22 /home/user/src/LaravelProj/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(197): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run()
#23 /home/user/src/LaravelProj/artisan(33): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle()
#24 {main}


Do you see all the text before " URI:"  written to the console?

yes............

That is super weird, I do not see that your facade or class is being run, the error is happening on a vendor level. Can you share the command? You can also throw an exception before the supposedly faulty line, and check the stack trace if the command file shows up, right now it is not showing on that stack trace so the error is something else

There is something weird in your code, you are trying to run a console command, hence getallheaders & $_SERVER won't be available, or trying to access it from a route where the STDOUT is not available by default

Issue seems to be caused by this code. When the output buffer is to be flushed it seems to do some post-processing and URI: seems to be something used internally for another reason. You could always write URL:
